# Crash in the Login / Registration screen Of firebase auth due to country restriction

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the codes below, I am checking the availability of the internet connection before the user can  Register /Login, everything working fine, But after I released the app, I noticed that users from specific centuries ( Syria – Jordan ) who have restrictions on the usage of the apps due to governmental rules, they got crash and app close when trying to Register new account or Login with a previously created accounts, another user not if they are from another country, I don’t want to bypass this as long it belongs to governments rules to control the country, but I want to Toast a message that notifies the user that this type of Registration / Login is forbidden in his country instead of crashing the app and sudden close.
Note:- Users who use proxy apps (VPN) are able to Register or Login to the same countries.
Please find the attached codes for Registration / Login.

///REGISTER ACTIVITY ///

```js
public void UserRegister() {
        emailed = email.getText().toString();
        passworded = password.getText().toString();

         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailed)){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, " ادخل عنوان بريد الكتروني اخر", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passworded)){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, " ادخل كلمة سر خاصة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else if (passworded.length()<8){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this," كلمة السر لا تقل عن 8 رموز", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else if (phone.length()<11) {
             Toast.makeText( Register.this, " رقم هاتف قصير", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
             return;
         }
        mDialog.setMessage("   جاري انشاء الحساب , شكرا لانتضارك...");
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailed,passworded).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    sendEmailVerification();
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    createAnewUser(task.getResult().getUser());
                    mAuth.signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Register.this,login.class));
                    Animatoo.animateWindmill(Register.this);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"   خطأ في انشاء حسابك ,  تحقق من المعلومات والاتصال", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mDialog.dismiss();



                }
            }
        });


    }
    //Email verification code using FirebaseUser object and using isSucccessful()function.
    public void sendEmailVerification() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user!=null){
            user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this,"    تم ارسال رسالة التفعيل الى بريدك , يرجى التحقق", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

//LOGIN ACTIVITY //

```js
    private void userlogin() {
        email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
        password = Password.getText().toString().trim();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(login.this, "تأكد من عنوان البريد الالكتروني", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(login.this, "كلمة مرور خاطئة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("email", email);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", password);
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        } else {
            loginPrefsEditor.clear();
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        }
        dialog.setMessage("جاري تسجيل الدخول , يرجى الانتظار..");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.show();
        if(isOnline()){ mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();


                    Toast.makeText(login.this, "تـأكد من المعلومات لطفاً", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    checkIfEmailVerified();

                }
            }
        });
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(login.this, "لا يوجد اتصال بالانترنت , تحقق من الاتصال لطفاً", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

    }


    private void checkIfEmailVerified(){
        FirebaseUser users=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        assert users != null;
        boolean emailVerified=users.isEmailVerified();
        if (emailVerified ){
            {
                Email.getText().clear();
                Password.getText().clear();
                Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                // Sending Email to Dashboard Activity using intent.
                intent.putExtra(userEmail,email);
                startActivity(intent);}

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText( this , "التحقق من البربد لطفاً" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 500 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: thanks for pointing this , I will edit it now .

Comment: It's probably because google services are not provided in some countries like Syria, Iran, etc. So figure out the way to check if the user is in one of the restricted countries and only show them the authentication feature if they are not in one of those countries.

Comment: nice idea, but how do I know which countries ALSO does facing same problem? , and how to figure the reason it does crash instead of just reject?